# New Development SharePoint Site

Tags: domain, setup

To creat a new SharePoint Site, I first created a new web application, then a new site collection at the root of that web application.

I bound the site to the domain `devsite` in IIS.

If I edit the server's host file pointing `devsite` to the localhost with the line

```
127.0.0.1   devsite
```

...it works great.

How can I make this `devsite` accessible from other machines on the network?

The network I am on is pretty big and I am trying to figure this out without bothering the admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to add an entry for 'devsite' to your network DNS or modify the hosts file on all of the machines to point to the actual IP address of your dev machine.  The 127.0.0.1 address would only work on the machine itself.

Comment: Can you unpack "add an entry for 'devsite' to your network DNS"?

Comment: That depends upon how your network is setup and what you use for an internal DNS server. Best to speak to your network administrator.

Comment: http://www.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm

Comment: I know what DNS is; I just didn't translate my understanding to the intranet side. Sent the request off to Systems Support. Until they get around to adding the entry I just added the entry to my host file. Thanks again.